# Real analysis. Uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Suppose $$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$$ is continuous and $f(x)=0$ for all $|x|>1$.

Show $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

This is not homework.  I'm trying to study for a test.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: This is spectacularly false. Take $f(x)=e^{\lvert x\rvert}$.

Comment: What does $f(x) > 0$ even mean for $f(x)$ a complex number? Do you perhaps mean $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: So sorry!  It was supposed to be f(x)=0.  I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

1. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[-2,2]$ by the theorem of your choice.
2. For a given $\varepsilon$, the $\delta<1$ obtained in 1. such that $|x-y|\lt \delta, x,y\in [-2,2]$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|\lt\varepsilon$ actually works for $x,y$ in the whole real line.